# SSL handshake aborted error while using Amazon API Gateway

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway

I am having an Android app with a few web services that run perfectly fine. But when I use the same webservices from AWS API Gateway, I am getting following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7933f1c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

I haven't yet enabled Client Certificate from API Gateway, but yet still I am getting this error.

I have checked device DateTime too. 
The webservices tend to work quite well on RestClient even without providing any Authorization. Am I doing something wrong ? TIA.

Comment: I'm facing same problem ? Do you want to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

SSL errors are often related to lack of SNI support in the client. API Gateway requires that the HTTP client supports SNI. I can't speak to the specifics for your Android app, but this blog post may help: http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-and-tlsv12-with-apache

Comment: Can you elaborate on this as I am very new to this ?

Comment: The blog link isnt available